# /proc/version show a gcc version, but I can't find the binary

Tags: linux, gcc

A Linux computer at my university does not have **gcc**, that is to say, when typing `gcc` in command prompt it gives: `/bin/sh: gcc: not found`

I was not able to find it with `whereis`, and `locate` gives me the following result:

```
/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/libgccpp.so.1
/usr/lib/libgccpp.so.1.0.2
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1/libgcc_s.so.1
/usr/share/doc/gcc-4.2-base
/usr/share/doc/gcc-4.2-base/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gcc-4.2-base/copyright
/usr/share/doc/gcc-4.2-base/README.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gcc-4.2-base/TODO.Debian
/usr/share/doc/libgcc1
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libgcc1
/usr/share/mysql/mysql-test/r/gcc296.result
/usr/share/mysql/mysql-test/t/gcc296.test
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gcc-4.2-base.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gcc-4.2-base.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gcc-4.2-base.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcc1.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcc1.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcc1.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcc1.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgcc1.shlibs
/var/www/skins/gcc
```

But the thing is, when typing `cat /proc/version`, I get:

> Linux version 2.6.22-14-server (buildd@palmer) (gcc version 4.1.3 20070929 (prerelease) (Ubuntu 4.1.2-16ubuntu2)) #1 SMP Sun Oct 14 23:34:23 GMT 2007

Why does `cat /proc/version` say it's present when it's not?

Answer (score 5):

`/proc/version` isn't saying that `gcc` is present, it's just giving the version of `gcc` that was used to build the kernel (on a build system somewhere).

Answer (score 3):

The gcc version displayed by `/proc/version` is the one used to compile your kernel, not the one installed on your system. Use `apt install gcc` to actually install it.